# Elastic : search two terms, one on _all, other one on a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to mix a search on a whole document (eg "developer") and a search on some field for another term (eg "php").
I can do each search separately but I can't mix them.

Here my example (simplified to show only my issue) :

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "_all": "developer"
        },
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "php",
          "fields": [
            "skills.description",
            "skills.description",
            "skills.details"
          ],
          "operator": "or",
          "type": "most_fields"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

If I run this example I have an error :

```
Parse Failure [Failed to parse source
```

Is there a way to search on both _all and specific fields with two terms?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're almost there, you need to combine them into a `bool/must` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "_all": "developer"
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "php",
                "fields": [
                  "skills.description",
                  "skills.description",
                  "skills.details"
                ],
                "operator": "or",
                "type": "most_fields"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```